# eslint issue for properties with underscore as prefix

Tags: node.js, mongoose, eslint

I am beginner in NodeJS and MongoDB, and while learning from some online resources I had created mongoose schema as:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const blogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: String,
  url: String,
  likes: Number,
})

blogSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString()
    delete returnedObject._id
    delete returnedObject.__v
  }
})
```

But eslint is keep giving me errors:

1. for `returnedObject.id`, `delete returnedObject._id` and `delete returnedObject.__v` - Assignment to property of function parameter 'returnedObject'.eslint(no-param-reassign)
2. for `returnedObject._id` and `returnedObject.__v` - Unexpected dangling '_' in '_id'.eslint(no-underscore-dangle)

[image: snapshot of the eslint errors]

What is the correct way in which I can remove the `_id` and `__v` fields and re-assign the `_id` to `id` for `returnedObject`?

I am using airbnb-base eslint configuration (`devDependencies` from `package.json`):

```js
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
```

Comment: This is fine, I think your eslint is configured far too strictly. TBH it seems to me like it doesn't make a distinction between an object and its properties, which is weird. (AFAIK `no-param-reassign` should only prevent you from reassigning `returnedObject` itself, and in the same way `no-underscore-dangle` should only complain about variables called `_id` for example, not properties...)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. However, if you MUST work with this lint rule then to make it stop complaining you can use a temporary variable: `let tmp = returnedObject; tmp.id = tmp._id.toString()` etc..

Comment: @CherryDT it seems the strict checking is coming from the airbnb eslint configuration. I wonder why it does not make distinction between and object and its properties.

Comment: @slebetman with assignment to a tmp object, the `no-param-reassign` issue is gone but it still complains about `no-underscore-dangle`.

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of that, because the property is called `_id` and there is nothing you can do. Try instead disabling the rule on the necessary line, by adding `// eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle` at the end.

Comment: @CherryDT wow... that's interesting to know to disable those warnings. but in a huge codebase like that that seems to be a repetitive task.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Airbnb linting rules and what the common practice is in this case, maybe check on their GitHub, I guess someone already asked this in the issues. Personally I'm using [Standard](https://standardjs.com/) which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested by @CherryDT and @slebetman in above comments - *there is nothing wrong with the code and the issue is only related to the eslint configuration*.

I come up with the following solutions:

#### Disable for line

Add a comment above the line where you see this error:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign, no-underscore-dangle
returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString()
```

or next to the line:

```
returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString() // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign, no-underscore-dangle
```

#### Disable for file

Add the comment at the first line in the file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign, no-underscore-dangle */
```

#### Turn off the rule in eslint configuation (usually `.eslintrc.js`, `.eslintrc.yml` or something similar with name `.eslintrc.*`)

```
rules: {
  no-underscore-dangle: off,
  no-param-reassign: off,
}
```

The example above if for the `yml` configuration, something similar can be done with other configurations.

The first two solutions are not good fit for a huge code base, so I recommend to use the third option.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Multiple errors can be turned off in the same comment with comma separated.</sub>